# Есть некоторая функция для подготовки строки на Javascript Нужно более элегантное решение

Tags: javascript

Оригинальная функция:

```
export const transformedSortFunc = (sortingPath) => {
  let transformPath;
  if (sortingPath) {
    if (sortingPath[0] === '-') {
      const sortingValue = get(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingPath.slice(1));
      transformPath = sortingValue ? `-${sortingValue}` : undefined;
    } else {
      transformPath = get(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingPath);
    }
  }
  return transformPath || sortingPath;
};

const SORTING_PATH_MAP = {
    asset: 'asset.type'
}
```

Возсожный пример фходящих параметров

```
  const conditional = [
        'id', 'asset', 'conditional', '-id', '-asset', '-conditional' ,
    ]
```

Используеться lodash можно и без него

Суть этой функции: принимаем определенную строку, для некотрых строк нужно вернуть эту строку с продолжением. Есть обьект `SORTING_PATH_MAP` с ключ значением что нужно вернуть. Но так-же эта строка может прийти с знаком "-"  в таком случае я его отбрасываю а потом добавляю. Для строк которых нет в `SORTING_PATH_MAP` ничего делать не нужно

Comment: как измеряется элегантность решения?

Comment: `sortingPath` - это имя свойства или может быть строка разделенная точками?

Comment: Как измеряться элегантность сложно сказать конечно.  sortingPath имя свойства точек там не ожидается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет меньше повторений в коде. Хотя они всё равно остались:

```
const map = (obj, value) => (value in obj) ? obj[value] : value;

const SORTING_PATH_MAP = {
    asset: 'asset.type'
};

const transformedSortFunc = sortingPath => {
    if (sortingPath[0] === '-') {
        return `-${map(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingPath.slice(1))}`;
    }
    return map(SORTING_PATH_MAP, sortingPath);
};
```

С помощью регулярного выражения можно избавиться от дублирования полностью. Код стал короче, читать стало сложнее. Отдельная функция `map` тоже теперь не нужна - она используется один раз:

```
const SORTING_PATH_MAP = {
    asset: 'asset.type'
};

const transformedSortFunc = sortingPath => {
    const m = sortingPath.match(/^(-?)(.*)$/);
    const v = (m[2] in SORTING_PATH_MAP) ? SORTING_PATH_MAP[m[2]] : m[2];
    return `${m[1]}${v}`;
};
```

Можно подготовить данные чтобы использовать меньше кода. Если вам нужно обработать много разных путей одной и той же картой, это хороший вариант:

```
const makeMap = map => {
    const emap = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
        emap[key] = value;
        emap[`-${key}`] = `-${value}`;
    }

    return value => (value in emap) ? emap[value] : value;
};

const SORTING_PATH_MAP = {
    asset: 'asset.type'
};

const transformedSortFunc = makeMap(SORTING_PATH_MAP);
```